# Pass by reference in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oracle

Hello I'm new to oracle and vb.net. I'm using vb.net for this application.
How I'm going to pass the result of the function from `GetMaterial` and `GetDescription` to the function `GetDate`  ? 
What should i do ?

```
  Private Function GetMaterial(ByVal strMaterial As String) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID = *****; Password = ***;"
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where device = 'xyz' "

    Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0

    Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet

End Function

Private Function GetDescription(ByVal strMaterial As String, ByVal ListBox1 As String) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID = ***; Password = ***;"
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where lpt = '" & ListBox1 & "' and device = '" & strMaterial & "'"


    Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0


    Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet

End Function

Private Function GetDate(ByVal strMaterial As String, ByVal ListBox1 As String, ByVal bdp1 As String) As DataSet

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source = ***; User ID = ***; Password = ***;"
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)


    Dim queryString As String = "select * from abc where tran_dttm <= to_date('1/31/2012','MM-DD-YYYY') and tran_dttm > to_date('1/30/2012','MM-DD-YYYY')"


    Dim sqlCommand As OracleClient.OracleCommand = New OracleClient.OracleCommand(queryString, sqlConnection)
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0


    Dim dataAdapter As OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter = New OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)

    Return dataSet

End Function
```

Comment: What is the ListBox1 and bdp1 parameters for? Would you care to elaborate its purpose?

Comment: i'm going to display the item which is search by number from function GetMaterial in certain code by function GetDescription on the date by function GetDate

Comment: Do you want to get records from "abc" Table and the user has the option if it is by Device, lpt and device or by tran_dttm? Or this 3 functions would be executed in sequence?

Comment: after passing function tran_dttm the function will be execute

Answer (score 0):

You can use ByRef if you will do some changes to the passed param, if you won't then use ByVal ...

```
Private Function GetDate(ByVal strMaterial As String, ByVal ListBox1 As String, ByVal bdp1 As String, ByVal dsM as Dataset, ByVal dsD as DataSet) As DataSet

'code here - example'
msgbox(dsD.Rows(0).Item(0))

End Function
```

So, if you will use function Getdate with getMaterial dan getDesc passed as param ....

```
Dim ds as DataSet = GetDate(.. , .. ,..  , getMaterial( ..), getDescription(..))
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand that

Comment: ByVal dsM as Dataset, ByVal dsD as DataSet

Comment: i still cant get it huhu. its ok tq

Comment: @Husna5207 : Can you show your last code and some error you've got .. ?